# w3c compliance checking tool to test my website locally

Tags: html, web, w3c, w3c-validation

I have developed a website in php 5+ which is yet to host in the server. I need to validate the website for w3c compliance and make sure that it meets W3C standards.

I am looking for a opensource tool which can be installed in windows environment .
please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it works in browser then it is more than a validation

Answer (score 1):

On top of EvilEpidemics answer they also have a page that has all their QA Tools available here - http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/

A part of me wants to acknowledge Ankits comment as well, don't thik full validation is the key, use it to help you, but don't make your ultimate aim full validation as you'll drive yourself mad!

EDIT: For Firefox if you download the [Web Developer Extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) there is an option under Tools called Validate Local HTML and Validate Local CSS, which will validate your document against the W3 Validator even if your page is on localhost.

Comment: *They're not downloadable, duh! It provides a page that gives you links off to their validation tools. Most of their validation tools allow file uploads as well, sop you're pages don't need to be on server for it to validate. Wait a sec and I'll change my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The W3C site has everything you are looking for already;

For code use;

http://www.validator.w3.org/‎

and for everything else pick a tool from;

http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete